# Why does MySQL COUNT+GROUP-BY take longer than just GROUP-BY

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I am just trying to understand the mechanics behind this. There are two queries

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count( id ) AS cnt FROM `users` GROUP BY country
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id FROM `users` GROUP BY country
```

id is primary, country is not indexed.
Why does query with count take much longer to run. From my understanding in order to GROUP-BY contents of the table, you anyway need to walk through all of the rows? If it is so, why it doesn't count as it groups things by? Or if it is not so, how does it manage to group-by without going through all rows, how does it manage to skip some of them?

Comment: I am really sorry, I copied a wrong query when creating the question. That has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There's no COUNT in your queries - are you sure this is the problem? All `AS cnt` does is rename that particular column. I'm almost 100% certain this is because you ran the first query you've listed here first, and thus when you ran the second one, MySQL could serve the results from memory rather than having to hit disk. The query is the same, after all - all you're changing is the name of the `id` column in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't involve any counting, if you want to count you should use

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(id) FROM `users` GROUP BY country
```

The first one is logically taking more time to run, because it is virtually creating a new table. (AS cnt does that)